# Keyboard not working when using "startx"

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg

I have a PC that shall run one single program. So I decided to go with startx instead of a whole Desktop Environment. The machine is a 64bit debian stretch machine.

I have edited my .xinitrc to launch the program, which works just fine (the program runs in fullscreen). The mouse works as expected, but the keyboard is not responding in any way.

The use is in the `input` group.

Here is the `id`for the user:

```
uid=1007(foifoi) gid=1009(foifoi) Gruppen=1009(foifoi),5(tty),20(dialout),24(cdrom),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),106(input),108(netdev),122(mlocate),1001(smbaccess),1008(maenners)
```

Here is the Xorg.log (could not post because too long):
https://pastebin.com/JsrzdHju

Here are the installed packages (xorg related):

```
ii  xorg                                 1:7.7+19                       amd64        X.Org X Window System
ii  xorg-docs-core                       1:1.7.1-1                      all          Core documentation for the X.org X Window System
ii  xorg-sgml-doctools                   1:1.11-1                       all          Common tools for building X.Org SGML documentation
ii  xserver-xorg                         1:7.7+19                       amd64        X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-core                    2:1.19.2-1+deb9u5              amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-all               1:7.7+19                       amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-input-evdev             1:2.10.5-1                     amd64        X.Org X server -- evdev input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-kbd               1:1.9.0-1+b1                   amd64        X.Org X server -- keyboard input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput          0.23.0-2                       amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-mouse             1:1.9.2-1+b1                   amd64        X.Org X server -- mouse input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-wacom             0.34.0-1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-legacy                  2:1.19.2-1+deb9u5              amd64        setuid root Xorg server wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all               1:7.7+19                       amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu            1.2.0-1+b1                     amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati               1:7.8.0-1+b1                   amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev             1:0.4.4-1+b5                   amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel             2:2.99.917+git20161206-1       amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau           1:1.0.13-3                     amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl               0.1.4+20161126git4d7160c-1     amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon            1:7.8.0-1+b1                   amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa              1:2.3.4-1+b2                   amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware            1:13.2.1-1+b1                  amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
```

I have no `xorg.conf`. The `evdev` module is loaded properly. Here is also the output of `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳   mini keyboard                           id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   mini keyboard                           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   mini keyboard                           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have keyboard events in `sudo evemu-record` or `sudo libinput debug-events`?